# Oracle SQL - Select users between two date by month

Tags: sql, oracle

I am learning SQL and I was wondering how to select active users by month, depending on their starting and ending date (both `timestamp(6)`). My table looks like this:

```
Cust_Num | Start_Date | End_Date
       1 | 2018-01-01 | 2019-01-01
       2 | 2018-01-01 | NULL
       3 | 2019-01-01 | 2019-06-01
       4 | 2017-01-01 | 2019-03-01
```

So, counting the active users by month, I should have an output like:

```
As of.     | Count
2018-06-01 | 3
...
2019-02-01 | 3
2019-07-01 | 1
```

So far, I do a manual operation by entering each month:

```sql
Select
    201906,
    count(distinct a.cust_num)
From
    active_users a
Where
    to_date(‘20190630’,’yyyymmdd) between a.start_date and nvl (a.end_date, ‘31-dec-9999)

union all

Select
    201905,
    count(distinct a.cust_num)
From
    active_users a
Where
    to_date(‘20190531’,’yyyymmdd) between a.start_date and nvl (a.end_date, ‘31-dec-9999)

union all
...
```

Not very optimized and sustainable if I want to enter 10 years ao 120 months lol.

Any help is welcome. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi Rambo, why the count = 1 when the date is 07/01/2019?There is no end date larger than 07/01/2019 in your example.

Comment: The value is null since the customer is still active, so he is part of the count () for every month following the start date. Therefore my NVL function.

Comment: Count is 1 because one user has a null value for the end date, meaning the user is still active, so if I run the query today I should have one active user. Hope it makes sense

Comment: Hi Rambo, Do you want to start from 2018-06-01 specifically? Since the minimum date is 2017-01-01 in your example but in your expected output, it starts with 2018-06-01. Which date range do you want?

Comment: Hi - No, not specifically from 2018-06-01. Actually in my database it starts from 2018-01-01. So I retrieve the active users since January 1st, 2018, by month.

Comment: What should the result be if a customer's `start_date` and `end_date` are both in the same month?

Comment: I want to count the active users at the end of each month where the end_date is null, so if the end_date is filled, it’s 0. Even if it’s either the 1st day of the month or the 28th.

Comment: @Rambo I think I've got a solution now. See my updated answer.

Comment: On `2019-02-01` there are 3 active users i.e. **Cust_Num  = 2,3,and 4**. Why your result is showing only 2 counts for that?

Comment: Thank you Dai I’m gonna have a look.

Comment: Hey Tejash, you’re right! I corrected.

Answer (score 1):

This query shows the active-user-count effective as-of the end of the month.

How it works:

1. Convert each input row (with `StartDate` and `EndDate` value) into **two** rows that represent a point-in-time when the active-user-count incremented (on `StartDate`) and decremented (on `EndDate`). We need to convert `NULL` to a far-off date value because `NULL` values are sorted before instead of after non-`NULL` values:

   This makes your data look like this:

   ```
   OnThisDate   Change
   2018-01-01        1
   2019-01-01       -1
   2018-01-01        1
   9999-12-31       -1
   2019-01-01        1
   2019-06-01       -1
   2017-01-01        1
   2019-03-01       -1
   ```
2. Then we simply `SUM OVER` the `Change` values (after sorting) to get the active-user-count as of that specific date:

   So first, sort by `OnThisDate`:

   ```
   OnThisDate   Change
   2017-01-01        1
   2018-01-01        1
   2018-01-01        1
   2019-01-01        1
   2019-01-01       -1
   2019-03-01       -1
   2019-06-01       -1
   9999-12-31       -1
   ```

   Then `SUM OVER`:

   ```
   OnThisDate   ActiveCount
   2017-01-01             1
   2018-01-01             2
   2018-01-01             3
   2019-01-01             4
   2019-01-01             3
   2019-03-01             2
   2019-06-01             1
   9999-12-31             0
   ```
3. Then we `PARTITION` (not group!) the rows by month and sort them by their date so we can identify the last `ActiveCount` row for that month (this actually happens in the `WHERE` of the outermost query, using `ROW_NUMBER()` and `COUNT()` for each month `PARTITION`):

   ```
   OnThisDate   ActiveCount    IsLastInMonth
   2017-01-01             1                1
   2018-01-01             2                0
   2018-01-01             3                1
   2019-01-01             4                0
   2019-01-01             3                1
   2019-03-01             2                1
   2019-06-01             1                1
   9999-12-31             0                1
   ```
4. Then filter on that where `IsLastInMonth = 1` (actually, where `ROW_COUNT() = COUNT(*)` inside each `PARTITION`) to give us the final output data:

   ```
   At-end-of-month     Active-count
   2017-01                        1
   2018-01                        3
   2019-01                        3
   2019-03                        2
   2019-06                        1
   9999-12                        0
   ```

This does result in "gaps" in the result-set because the `At-end-of-month` column only shows rows where the `Active-count` value actually changed rather than including all possible calendar months - but that's ideal (as far as I'm concerned) because it excludes redundant data. Filling in the gaps can be done inside your application code by simply repeating output rows for each additional month until it reaches the next `At-end-of-month` value.

Here's the query using T-SQL on SQL Server (I don't have access to Oracle right now). And here's the SQLFiddle I used to come to a solution: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/ad68b7/24

```
SELECT
  OtdYear,
  OtdMonth,
  ActiveCount
FROM
  (

    -- This query adds columns to indicate which row is the last-row-in-month ( where RowInMonth == RowsInMonth )
    SELECT
      OnThisDate,
      OtdYear,
      OtdMonth,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY OtdYear, OtdMonth ORDER BY OnThisDate ) AS RowInMonth,
      COUNT(*) OVER ( PARTITION BY OtdYear, OtdMonth ) AS RowsInMonth,
      ActiveCount
    FROM
      (
        SELECT
          OnThisDate,
          YEAR( OnThisDate ) AS OtdYear,
          MONTH( OnThisDate ) AS OtdMonth,
          SUM( [Change] ) OVER ( ORDER BY OnThisDate ASC ) AS ActiveCount
        FROM
          (
            SELECT
              StartDate AS [OnThisDate],
              1 AS [Change]
            FROM
              tbl

            UNION ALL

            SELECT
              ISNULL( EndDate, DATEFROMPARTS( 9999, 12, 31 ) ) AS [OnThisDate],
              -1 AS [Change]
            FROM
              tbl
          ) AS sq1
      ) AS sq2
  ) AS sq3
WHERE
  RowInMonth = RowsInMonth
ORDER BY
  OtdYear,
  OtdMonth
```

This query *can* be flattened into fewer nested queries by using aggregate and window functions directly instead of using aliases (like `OtdYear`, `ActiveCount`, etc) but that would make the query much harder to understand.

Comment: But I think his dbms is Oracle and your answer looks like SQL Server.

Comment: @Lawrence Sorry, yes - I've added a disclaimer to my answer. I don't have access to an Oracle server right now to test it.

Answer (score 1):

I have created the query which will give the result of all the months starting from the minimum start date in the table till maximum end date.

You can change it using adding one condition in WHERE clause.

```
-- table creation

CREATE TABLE ACTIVE_USERS (CUST_NUM NUMBER, START_DATE DATE, END_DATE DATE)

-- data creation

INSERT INTO ACTIVE_USERS
SELECT * FROM 
(
SELECT 1, DATE '2018-01-01', DATE '2019-01-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, DATE '2018-01-01', NULL              FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, DATE '2019-01-01', DATE '2019-06-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, DATE '2017-01-01', DATE '2019-03-01' FROM DUAL
)

-- data in the actual table

SELECT * FROM ACTIVE_USERS ORDER BY CUST_NUM;

  CUST_NUM START_DATE END_DATE  
---------- ---------- ----------
         1 2018-01-01 2019-01-01
         2 2018-01-01           
         3 2019-01-01 2019-06-01
         4 2017-01-01 2019-03-01
```

**Query to fetch desired result**

```
WITH CTE ( START_DATE, END_DATE ) AS 
(
    SELECT
        ADD_MONTHS( START_DATE, LEVEL - 1 ),
        ADD_MONTHS( START_DATE, LEVEL ) - 1
    FROM
    (
        SELECT
            MIN( START_DATE ) AS START_DATE,
            MAX( END_DATE   ) AS END_DATE
        FROM
            ACTIVE_USERS
    )
    CONNECT BY LEVEL <= CEIL( MONTHS_BETWEEN( END_DATE, START_DATE ) ) + 1
) 
--
--
SELECT    
    C.START_DATE,
    COUNT(1) AS CNT
FROM
    CTE C
    JOIN ACTIVE_USERS D ON
    (
        C.END_DATE BETWEEN
            D.START_DATE
            AND
            CASE
                WHEN D.END_DATE IS NOT NULL THEN D.END_DATE
                ELSE C.END_DATE
            END
    )
GROUP BY
    C.START_DATE
ORDER BY
    C.START_DATE;
```

**-- output --**

```
START_DATE        CNT
---------- ----------
2017-01-01          1
2017-02-01          1
2017-03-01          1
2017-04-01          1
2017-05-01          1
2017-06-01          1
2017-07-01          1
2017-08-01          1
2017-09-01          1
2017-10-01          1
2017-11-01          1

START_DATE        CNT
---------- ----------
2017-12-01          1
2018-01-01          3
2018-02-01          3
2018-03-01          3
2018-04-01          3
2018-05-01          3
2018-06-01          3
2018-07-01          3
2018-08-01          3
2018-09-01          3
2018-10-01          3

START_DATE        CNT
---------- ----------
2018-11-01          3
2018-12-01          3
2019-01-01          3
2019-02-01          3
2019-03-01          2
2019-04-01          2
2019-05-01          2
2019-06-01          1

30 rows selected.
```

Cheers!!