# Transpose and fill missing dates in date range

Tags: sql

First, my main issue, I want to do is to check how many users that had an active product on a given date.

My data looks like this:

```
UserID        ActiveFrom       ActiveTo
1                2019-02-03       2019-03-05
2                2019-04-01       2019-04-30
1                2019-03-06       2019-04-04
3                2019-05-01       2019-05-31
```

I think the solution could to select all the ActiveFrom and union with ActiveFrom, and then fill in the missing dates so that it looked something like this:

```
UserID     ActiveOnDate
1              2019-02-03
1              2019-02-04
1              2019-02-05
And so on
```

Then I could count all the UserID for each date. But i can’t find a query that fills out the missing dates in the date range. And I also don’t know if this is the “easiest” solution. Any ideas?

Comment: I find that trying to "fill in missing data" using SQL is an exercise in pain (as SQL is designed to query _existing_ data, not to generate new data). How are you wanting to process the generated data?

Comment: Yes I figured that to, but I want to process/visualise the data in Microsoft Power BI and would like to have the data as “ready” as possible. But, as mentioned maybe there is a better way of finding the count of active users per a given date, but I can’t figure it out.

Comment: I answered a similar question a few months ago - does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/57281132/159145 - my answer doesn't use "filling in missing dates" as a solution.

Answer (score 0):

If your Dates have the Date datatype (and not VARCHAR for exemple), you can use the BETWEEN sql operator
https://sql.sh/cours/where/between

```
SELECT count(*) FROM user WHERE [dateToTest] BETWEEN ActiveFrom AND ActiveTo;
```